# Warning message should be placed at top in Android app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app

In posting answer screen, it shows you warning message if you don't enter >30 characters but it **doesn't look noticeable** easily due to the visibility of keyboard in the screen.

But if you check question posting screen, it shows you warning message at top and its easily noticeable.

And, don't you think warning/error message should be having RED background/font color?

[image]

Comment: Those checks and X-s need to be freehand. [tag:status-no-freehand-things]

Comment: @jeffreylin_ why so? and check and correct the link.

Comment: @PareshMayani it is a [meme on Meta SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/182513) regarding freehand circles and other markings in images.  And jeffrey's link is not broken, he is just linking to a mythical tag indicating that lack of freehand circles.  It is just an attempt at humor.

Comment: @Qantas nice circles, but please use the upload utility to avoid image rot. You can upload the image via the answer editor then paste the resulting URL.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: thanks for reminding me.

Comment: @Qantas sure, just saw too many images rot away over time to be lost forever. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah yes - this will be fixed in the next release v0.1.10

Comment: Yes its fixed in 0.1.10 version. Thanks